# two monitors and unity workspaces settings

Tags: unity, workspaces

I have two monitors on my Ubuntu system. Ubuntu recognized two monitors perfectly well. I use unity for workspace settings. The issue is when I seperate the screen on workspace settings in unity, two monitors are seperated together. Let's name the monitors 1 and 2. When I click one of the workspaces in monitor 1, monitor 2 also changes the workspace. I want to monitor 2 always output the same workspace, but it is not possible. Is there any workaround or options for the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Try `gnome-tweaks`, Workspaces/Display handling and set 'Workspaces on primary display only'.

Comment: Is the Workspaces/Display handeling menu appear only when two monitors are connected? I no longer have the two monitor setting, but I want to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution (depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve), might be to set the window(s) that you want always on show, to be visible on every workspace, or rather: always on the visible workspace.

To do this - right click on the menu bar of the window(s) you want to see all the time, and select "Always on Visible Workspace".